# How to check in Ruby rails, if a word is present in value of a string which is part of jsonb column in postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `User` table in `postgres`. In rails console I search for `User.where(<myWhereClause>).count`

I have `jsonb` column called as "criteria".

Within `criteria` for key `eligibility`, I want to see if the value contains my search term `'directMBA'`

`eligibility` is a comma separated string - `'directMBA, correspondanceMBA, onlineMBA'`

This doesn't work

```
User.where("criteria->>'eligibility'.include?('directMBA')").count
```

I don't want the sql query. 
I need the Ruby Rails code to run in console

PS:
Also, what if my keyword is 'directMBA' or 'onlineMBA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [SQL LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator

```
User.where("criteria->>'eligibility' LIKE '%directMBA%'").count

# Also, what if my keyword is 'directMBA' or 'onlineMBA'
User.where("criteria->>'eligibility' LIKE '%directMBA%' OR LIKE '%onlineMBA%'").count
```